# Running continuos thread in app delegate is proper or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app requirement is, when the app is launch for the first time it will send request to server to get data, parse it and save it in document folder which will be used across entire project.Again after particular time interval the app will send request to server to get updated data(if any) and update that data in document folder, which again will be updated across entire project.All this process is happening in background thread.This process will repeat until the app is running in foreground once the user close the app, the app will get terminate, it will not go in background.

This repeated request I am creating in app delegate as well as doing xml parsing once the data is received and saving after parsing. Now my question is, Is this proper means doing too much stuff in app delegate is safe or there is some limitation or is this bad programming?

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with torrey.lyons to an extent.  I think creating singletons is bad practice generally speaking and should be avoided where possible.  One thing you should never do is code a class so that it *has* to be a singleton.  Purpose built singletons tend to increase coupling and can be really problematic when it comes to unit testing where you might want to replace your singleton with a stub class or you might need it to be reinitialised for each unit test.

If this task of getting data is an application level task, there is absolutely no reason why it can't logically be located in the application delegate.  I would however create a "connection manager" as torrey.lyons suggests and have one as a property of the app delegate.

I would also not use an explicit background thread to do the data update but I would use a subclass of [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).  This is a whole lot easier than managing your own thread.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyP for your suggestion.I implemented NSOperation and it is far more useful and better than NSThread.

Comment: Hi @JeremyP, in NSOperation is it necessary to notify client of each and every state of operation object.I mean is it necessary to override following methods: start, isConcurrent, isExecuting and isFinished?

Comment: @NuzhatZari No.  All you need to override is the main method (as long as you put it on a NSOperationQueue).  Alternatively, use a NSBlockOperation and give it a block to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice. Your app delegate should ideally be concerned purely with its own responsibilities, i.e.. responding to the messages the application sends its delegate. It is much better to split off other discrete responsibilities into other objects. For example, you could have a "connection manager" object that is responsible for periodically communicating with the server. If you are sure the app will only connect to one server at a time you probably want to use the singleton pattern so that there only one instance of the object in your application and it can be easily reached by any other class. A good discussion of the proper role of the app delegate and singletons can be found on at [Singletons, AppDelegates and top-level data](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html). A good general overview on writing singletons can be found under the [Care and Feeding of Singletons](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-02-care-and-feeding-of-singletons.html).